# Padding-top not working

Tags: html, css

Padding on the instagram portion not working, cannot figure out why. It just seems to stay at the top and changing some css doesn't work.

```
        <style>
        body {min-width: 1024px; background-color: #ffffff;}
        .site_header {background-color: #f4f4f4; border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea; position: relative; z-index: 5000; height: 75px;}
        .site_wrap {margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 75px;}
        .site_navbar {width: 512px; float: left;}
        .site_logo {padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; line-height: 45px; float: left; width: 256px;}
        .site_logo_image {background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/DjqnQ54.png); display: block; height: 45px; width: 128px; overflow: hidden; text-indent: 100%; white-space: nowrap;}
        .site_links {padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; line-height: 45px; float: left; width: 256px; display: block;}
        .site_links_instagram {background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/cVv38jI.png);}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site_header">
        <div class="site_wrap">
            <nav class="site_navbar">
                <div class="site_logo">
                    <a href="/home" title="Homepage" class="site_logo_image">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class"site_links">
                    <a href="/instagram" title="Instagram" class="site_links_instagram">Instagram</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `<div class"site_links">` which needs to be `<div class="site_links">`. Looks like a simple typo.

Comment: Thanks; must look out for those in the future.